# How to put three columns in a row in 16 column grid system of BOOTSTRAP

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing a very indent problem where I need to keep three columns in a row and I have a customized BOOTSTRAP with 16 grid system. 
For a 12 grid system it is very easy to divide three columns in a row by putting 3 columns by putting col-lg-4 . 
How can we achieve the same thing in 16 grid system

Alluring answer will be appreciated .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What have you tried yourself, we don't just provide code, we help when you have problems (after you've done debugging). As your new please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

```
.col-third {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Then you may have to change some css at the mobile views as bootstraps rows have a negative padding at smaller screens.